# How to set focus on Form forcefully even when ALT+TAB is pressed

Tags: c#, forms

I am implementing a program, where a form should be opened while system is starting and user should enter data in some of form fields,Then only user can access information in the system. I added this program to Task Scheduler so that program is getting executed while system starting.
**Any help for forcing user to fill form fields while system is starting?**

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this. Windows will not allow this to happen. If this was allowed, and two programs tried to do this simultaneously, there's no telling how it would affect your system.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your question is not clear, it's better to give more information about your scenario

but I will try to give some information.

1- you can make the application to be runnable at windows start app by using the following code

```
  RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true));

            key.SetValue("My Program", "\"" + Application.ExecutablePath + "\"");
```

2- Then you can make your program run at the top most by

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace LicenseManager {

  public static class WinApi {

    [DllImport( "user32.dll" )]
    static extern bool SetWindowPos( IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags );

    static private IntPtr HWND_TOPMOST = new IntPtr( -1 );

    private const uint SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
    private const uint SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002;

    static public void MakeTopMost( Form f ) {
      SetWindowPos( f.Handle, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE );
    }

  }
}
```

3- and you can prevent the user from closing the app until he enter the required data by checking your login at closing event

```
private void Form2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult userAnswer = MessageBox.Show ("Do you wish to close ALL " + counterLabel.Text + " of the 'Form2' forms?", "Close ALL Forms?", 
            MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

        if (userAnswer == DialogResult.Yes)
            this.Dispose();
    }
```